# generate a vector with set number of 1s

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I want to generate a large vector of just 0's and 1's of arbitrary length. But I want at max 10 1's in the vector. 
(For those familiar, a 10-sparse vector of some arbitrary length)
How can I do this in R/Rstudio

Comment: It is easy enough to generate a 0-1 vector with exactly 10 1's . But, you said that you want a vector with a *max* of 10 1's. Your problem is under-specified. What is the probability distribution on the possibles 1-counts (which per your problem description could be any number in the range 0,1,2,...,10). The problem with using a uniform distribution on 0-10 is that there are more binary vectors with 10 1's than e.g. 7 1's, so you would be biasing the vectors themselves if you don't bias the counts properly.

Comment: I don't agree that the linked question is a duplicate. That question has a twist that this question lacks (a nonuniform distribution on the probabilities of 1's occurring at various indices) and this question seems to have a twist that the other question lacks (a maximum number of 1's rather than a fixed number of 1's).

Answer (score 0):

```
rep(0,n) #generate n zeros
sample(0:10,1) #generate random number between 0 and 10
rep(1,sample(0:10,1)) # generate random number of ones
sample(c(rep(0,n),rep(1,sample(0:10,1)))) # combine and permute
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# function that generates a 10-sparce vector
GenerateSparceVector = function(N) {

    # number of 1s
    n = sample(1:10,1)

    # create vector
    vec = c(rep(1, n), rep(0, N-n))

    # randomise vector
    sample(vec) }

# for reproducibility
set.seed(32)

# apply the function
GenerateSparceVector(20)

# [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Note that I assumed you need at least one `1` in your vector.

Every time you run it there's an equal probability of getting 1, 2, 3, ... 10 `1`s in your vector.